# AWS S3 copy object downloads it locally?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am interested to know whether, when copying an S3 object from 1 bucket to another, the object gets downloaded to the client, even temporarily?
I am using AWS javascript SDK: s3.copyObject(...)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not downloaded localy. They are executed on the AWS side.

They are free within the [same region](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/):

> Transfers **between S3 buckets** or from Amazon S3 to any service(s) within the same AWS Region **are free**.

Recent AWS blog post explains copying between buckets:

- [How can I copy objects between Amazon S3 buckets?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/move-objects-s3-bucket/)

Comment: Note that, per [Copying Objects](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/copy-object.html) "to copy an object that is greater than 5 GB, you must use the multipart upload API."